# ignore files in flight

Tags: c#

When I run the code below, it fills my array with a list of files in the specified directory.

This is good.

However, it also grabs files that are 'in flight' - meaning files that are currently being copied to that directory.

This is bad.

How do I go about ignoring those 'in-flight' files? Is there a way to check each file to make sure it's 'fully there' before I process it?

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("sourcePath"));
        if (files.Length > 0)
        {

            foreach (string filename in files)
            {
                string filenameonly = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                AMPFileEntity afe = new AMPFileEntity(filenameonly);
                afe.processFile();
            }

        }
```

Comment: +1 Flying files ... there's a new one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can try to open the file for writing. If you are able to open for writing without an exception then it's likely not "in-flight" anymore. Unfortunately, I have encountered this problem several times before and have not come across a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is no way to achieve what you are looking for.  Robert's suggestion of opening the file for writing solves a subset of the problem but does not solve the bigger issue which is

> The file system is best viewed as a multi-threaded object over which you have no synchronization capabilities

No matter what synchronization construct you try to use to put the file system into a "known state", there is a way for the user to beat it.

The best way to approach this problem is to process the files as normal and catch the exceptions that result from using files that are "in flight".  This is the only sane way to deal with the file system.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a list of files in the directory.
2. Get a list of open handles (see below).
3. Remove the latter from the former.

You can get a list of open handles by p/invoking NtQuerySystemInformation. There's [a project on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/OpenedFileFinder.aspx?fid=422864&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=2277170) that shows how to do this. Alternatively, you can call [Handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx), from Sysinternals, and parse its output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename/move the file. If you can rename it, it's no longer in use.

Comment: It was no longer in use.  The moment the rename completes it could be in use again.  You can't control the file system :)

Answer (score 0):

Carra's answer gave me an idea.

If you have access to the program that copies the files to this directory, modify it so that it:

1. Writes files to a temporary directory on the same disk.
2. Move the files to the appropriate folder after they're finished writing to disk.

On the same filesystem, a move operation just updates the directory entries rather than changing the file's physical location on disk.  Which means that it's extremely fast.

Comment: If you want true reliability this still won't work.  Other processes on the machine could decide to delete that new folder as they please.  You can't stop this from happening.  The file system is fundamentally unpredictable